# copy multiple files with certain prefixs

Tags: bash, cp

How do i copy files with with the certain prefixs e.g. `LTE*.html`, `Voicemail*.html`

```
$ ls
2G_3G_cccccc.html  other_dddd.html   other3_dddd.html  Voicemail_bbbbbb.html
LTE_aaaa.html      other2_dddd.html  subdir1
```

I have tried this but no joy

```
$ cp '(LTE*|Voice*).html' subdir1/
cp: cannot stat `(LTE*|Voice*).html': No such file or directory
```

So this would be the result I want

```
$ ls subdir1/
Voicemail_bbbbbb.html    LTE_aaaa.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brace expansion

```
cp {LTE,Voice}*.html subdir1/
```

Which expands to

```
cp LTE*.html Voice*.html subdir1/
```